# Python PyAutoGUI return "ImageNotFoundException", but "except" doesn't recognise it as an exception

Tags: python, exception, pyautogui, except

With the previous version of pyautogui, when an image wasn't found the return was "None", so I used to handle it with `except TypeError:`.
But since the update (version 0.9.41), it isn't working, as it's returning ImageNotFoundException, but it isn't recognised as an exception. When I try to do `except ImageNotFoundException:` it gives the error:

> [E0712] Catching an exception which doesn't inherit from Exception: ImageNotFoundException

How should this error be handled?

Comment: You're using python 2 right ?

Comment: I'm using Spyder and Python 3.7.

Comment: if it is "returning ImageNotFoundException", why not `if isinstance(image, ImageNotFoundException): pass`

Comment: Tried.. But I get `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fine with `pyautogui 0.9.52` and `python 3.9.0`

```
import pyautogui

# force use of ImageNotFoundException
pyautogui.useImageNotFoundException()

try:
    location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('foo.png')
    print('image found')
except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
    print('ImageNotFoundException: image not found')
```

I found the `useImageNotFoundException()` part in this page [locateCenterOnScreen doesn't raise ImageNotFoundException. · Issue #441 · asweigart/pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/441). If `useImageNotFoundException()` is not called, `locateOnScreen()` just returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, and also couldn't figure out why handling this with an except wasn't possible. Now I have figured it out on python 3.7, this should work if you've installed the PyScreeze package:
from pyscreeze import ImageNotFoundException

I hope it can help you out :)

Comment: And also I got PyScreeze automatically when I downloaded PyAutoGui.

Comment: This worked! Just had to import "ImageNotFoundException" from PyScreeze. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just force pyautogui to use ImageNotFoundException. Use this line when initializing pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.useImageNotFoundException()
```

Do not use pyscreeze's ImageNotFoundException.
As we can see on class ImageNotFoundException definition, the developer points out it's not an ideal use:

```
class ImageNotFoundException(PyAutoGUIException):
"""
This exception is the PyAutoGUI version of PyScreeze's `ImageNotFoundException`, which is raised when a locate*()
function call is unable to find an image.

Ideally, `pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException` should never be raised by PyAutoGUI.
"""
```