# How would I prevent a python script that loops forever from using all my ram?

Tags: python

I want to automate the process of clicking a few buttons in a game, so I wrote a script that looks for the first button and clicks it, then clicks the other two.

```py
import pyautogui as pag
import time

while True:
    if Click("Replay") == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        Click("Continue")
        time.sleep(1)
        Click("Repeat")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

The `Click()` function basically takes a string input and turns it into input.png, matches it to a png i have of the buttons, and clicks it. If it doesn't find it, it just says it couldnt find it.

Heres that in case you need it:

```py
def Click(image):
    image = str(image)
    location = pag.locateOnScreen(image + ".png")
    if location != None:
        point = pag.center (location)
        coordsX, coordsY = point
        pag.click(coordsX, coordsY)
        print("Clicked %s" % (image))
        return True
    else:
        print("Did not find %s Button" % (image))
```

My end goal was to make it into an executable so I could send it to people and they could use it, but I don't want it to waste a lot of memory on the computers it runs on. I also don't want to increase the wait time on it, and I believe I saw somewhere it clears itself after 2GB or something, but I'm not that good at coding and I dont want it using that much ram in the first place. Is there anything I can do to either A. clear it at a lower threshold, or B. make it not use that much ram in the first place?

Comment: Where do you even see a possibility that this script will need more and more RAM?

Answer (score 0):

A few optimizations/cleanups to your code:

1. You don't need the else for `time.sleep(5)`.
2. Consider adding a `return False` to your `Click()` function's else clause?
3. [Pyautogui's website](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) says that the `locateOnScreen` function will raise an error now, not return `None`, so consider using a try-except block. (If it doesn't return an exception for you, refer to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461133/python-pyautogui-return-imagenotfoundexception-but-except-doesnt-recognise).)
4. Pyautogui allows clicking a Point object, so use this instead:

```
def Click(image):
    image = str(image)
    try:
        pag.click(pag.locateCenterOnScreen(image + ".png"))
        print("Clicked %s" % (image))
        return True
    except pag.ImageNotFoundException:
        print("Did not find %s Button" % (image))
        return False
```

I've run this code,and it uses almost no RAM for me.